# Passing json content using telnet

Tags: json, http, curl, telnet

I'm trying to pass json using telnet, here is my usecase:

```
mohamadm-mac:~ mohamadm$ telnet 192.168.56.5 8081
Trying 192.168.56.5...
Connected to ip-192-168-56-5.eu-west-1.compute.internal.
Escape character is '^]'.
PUT http://192.168.56.5:8081/artifactory/api/repositories/test-local HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
{"rclass" : "local"}

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Artifactory/5.8.4
X-Artifactory-Id: 84c66c5bb11d016e:-6e6f432f:161a8395cb7:-8000
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 02 Mar 2018 16:25:40 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "No content to map to Object due to end of input"
  } ]
}Connection closed by foreign host.
```

How can I resolve this? I need to use telnet like the following curl:

```
curl -XPUT http://192.168.56.5:8081/artifactory/api/repositories/test-local -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"rclass" : "local"}' -uadmin:password
```

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: have you tried `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: tried it but the same error